# How to create a variadic template string formatter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, string-formatting, variadic-templates

We need to format strings all the time. It would be so nice to be able to say:

```
std::string formattedStr = format("%s_%06d.dat", "myfile", 18); // myfile_000018.dat
```

Is there a C++ way of doing this? Some alternatives I considered:

- `snprintf`: uses raw `char` buffers. Not nice in modern C++ code.
- `std::stringstream`: does not support format pattern strings, instead you must push clumsy iomanip objects into the stream.
- `boost::format`: uses an ad-hoc operator overload of `%` to specify the arguments. Ugly.

Isn't there a better way with variadic templates now that we have C++11?

Comment: @ruslo It seems that it can't automatically produce an std::string result. Also the required syntax is too weird to be used all over a project.

Answer (score 14):

It can certainly be written in C++11 with variadic templates. It's best to wrap something that already exists than to try to write the whole thing yourself. If you are already using Boost, it's quite simple to wrap `boost::format` like this:

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <string>

namespace details
{
    boost::format& formatImpl(boost::format& f)
    {
        return f;
    }

    template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
    boost::format& formatImpl(
        boost::format& f,
        Head const& head,
        Tail&&... tail)
    {
        return formatImpl(f % head, std::forward<Tail>(tail)...);
    }
}

template <typename... Args>
std::string format(
        std::string formatString,
        Args&&... args)
{
    boost::format f(std::move(formatString));
    return details::formatImpl(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...).str();
}
```

You can use this the way you wanted:

```
std::string formattedStr = format("%s_%06d.dat", "myfile", 18); // myfile_000018.dat
```

If you don't want to use Boost (but you really should) then you can also wrap `snprintf`. It is a bit more involved and error-prone, since we need to manage char buffers and the old style non-type-safe variable length argument list. It gets a bit cleaner by using `unique_ptr`'s:

```
#include <cstdio> // snprintf
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept> // runtime_error
#include <memory> // unique_ptr

namespace details
{
    template <typename... Args>
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> formatImplS(
            size_t bufSizeGuess,
            char const* formatCStr,
            Args&&... args)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[bufSizeGuess]);

        size_t expandedStrLen = std::snprintf(buf.get(), bufSizeGuess, formatCStr, args...);

        if (expandedStrLen >= 0 && expandedStrLen < bufSizeGuess)
        {
            return buf;
        } else if (expandedStrLen >= 0
                   && expandedStrLen < std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max())
        {
            // buffer was too small, redo with the correct size
            return formatImplS(expandedStrLen+1, formatCStr, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        } else {
            throw std::runtime_error("snprintf failed with return value: "+std::to_string(expandedStrLen));
        }
    }

    char const* ifStringThenConvertToCharBuf(std::string const& cpp)
    {
        return cpp.c_str();
    }

    template <typename T>
    T ifStringThenConvertToCharBuf(T const& t)
    {
        return t;
    }
}

template <typename... Args>
std::string formatS(std::string const& formatString, Args&&... args)
{
    // unique_ptr<char[]> calls delete[] on destruction
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> chars = details::formatImplS(4096, formatString.c_str(),
                details::ifStringThenConvertToCharBuf(args)...);

    // string constructor copies the data
    return std::string(chars.get());
}
```

There are some differences between `snprintf` and `boost::format` in terms of format specification but your example works with both.

Comment: All of your code is missing `std::forward` and `std::move`, and makes an unnecessary copy of `formatString`

Comment: As an alternative (not a correction) there's this trick which compacts it all and avoids recursion entirely, but clang complains about the unused local variable: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed07c49c0d53266f

Comment: I take it back, boost format takes a `const string&`, so it's less clear if there's an unnecessary copy or not.  I've altered my version to clearly not make a copy: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a00e97261e3c39e

Comment: @isarandi "It can certainly be written in C++11 with variadic templates". Can you please provide an answer regarding this C++ 11 solution?

Comment: @doofx well, that's this answer itself :)

Comment: @isarandi apologize, I somehow missed the second answer! thank you

Answer (score 1):

The [fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) implements exactly that, string formatting using variadic templates. Example:

```
// printf syntax:
std::string formattedStr = fmt::sprintf("%s_%06d.dat", "myfile", 18);

// Python-like syntax:
std::string formattedStr = fmt::format("{}_{:06}.dat", "myfile", 18);
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of the library.